# TypeScript - Pass object literal to class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can you pass default values to a class constructor? Here, `last` returns `undefined`.

```
class greatFunction {
    options: {
        names:  {first: 'Joe', last: 'Bloggs'}
    }
    constructor(options) {
        console.log(options.names.first + ' ' + options.names.last);        
    }
}
```

Called:

```
new greatFunction({
    names: {
        first: 'Paul'
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with typescript but, within your constructor you could set the default by using `options.names.last = options.name.last || "default"` if the first side of the check (left from `||`) is true, that value is taken, if it is false, the right side is taken. Since undefined is false, it defaults to `"default"`

Comment: @Dellirium Yup I know that but looking for tidier way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want your param name to be the same as a local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting default values:

```
class GreatFunction {
  options: {
    names:  {first: 'Joe', last: 'Bloggs'}
  }
  constructor({names: {first=this.options.names.first: firstName, last=this.options.names.last: lastName}}) {
    console.log(`${firstName} ${lastName}`)        
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use a library, for example [lodash.defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) seems to fit your use case.

Comment: "The language only supports setting a default for function parameters themselves"  this refers to typescript, or javascript (in case of javascript, how? o.0)

Comment: Both, really... `constructor({first=this.options.first, last=this.options.last}) { console.log(first + ' ' + last)}`

Answer (score 3):

instead of doing that why dont you create an interface like this

```
interface names { 
      firstname:string;
      lastname ?: string;
  }
```

Since you can't create make a property of a parameter optional.

Or you do the hard way which is like this

```
interface IOptions{
names:INames;
     }

 interface  INames {
    first:string;
    last?:string;
  }

   class greatFunction{

        constructor (options:IOptions){
          options.names.last = options.names.last?options.names.last:'Default';
       console.log(options.names.first + ' ' + options.names.last)
    }
 }

   new greatFunction({names:{first:'Theophilus'}});
```

It should return the default in console

Answer (score 0):

You do need to pass **something** to the function, so one option would be to try something like this:

```
class greatFunction {
    defaultOptions = {
        names: { first: 'Joe', last: 'Bloggs' }
    }
    constructor(options) {
        if (options == null)
            options = this.defaultOptions;
        console.log(options.names.first + ' ' + options.names.last);
    }
}
```

You can then create a new `greatFunction` using:

```
let x = new greatFunction(null)
```

Or:

```
let y = new greatFunction({ names: { first: 'Test', last: 'Blah' } });
```

**Alternatively**, don't do it using the constructor, and use a property after initialising.  For example:

```
class greatFunction {
    public options = {
        names: { first: 'Joe', last: 'Bloggs' }
    }
    constructor() { }
    doSomething() {
        console.log(this.options.names.first + ' ' + this.options.names.last);
    }
}
```

and then use with:

```
let x = new greatFunction();
x.options = { names: { first: 'Test', last: 'Blah' } };
x.doSomething();
```

Comment: This is good, but what if all options are optional, and if the option is not passed through it will use the default for that option. I don't want it to be either pass all options or pass none.